# How to set break point in JSX script

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering why I cannot set a break point in JSX a script when I tried to debug it.  Does that mean there is no way to set breakpoint in Chrome if I cannot get the actually transpiled JS script? If so, is there a way to get the transpiled JS source from Chrome without any 3rd party tool?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `debugger`?

```
// In your JSX.
<span>{debugger}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, so this means I can not do what I mentioned right? Anyway, do you have any tutorial link for this?

Comment: I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost:3000/scripts/code.jsx: Unexpected token (11:7)